# Symfony2 and Doctrine: createQuery error

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to run this query:

```
$query =  $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
            'SELECT MDPIBackendBundle:Articles   
            FROM MDPIBackendBundle:Articles art
            LEFT JOIN MDPIBackendBundle:ScopusFTPUploads uploaded_art WITH art.id = uploaded_art.article_id
            WHERE uploaded_art.article_id IS NULL AND art.pubdate_published >= "'.$startDate.'" AND art.pubdate_published < "'.$endDate.'"'
    );
```

And I am geting this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 272: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'
```

Do you know where is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a typo, you cant use `"` in `sql`/`dql`. Try:

```
$query =  $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
            "SELECT MDPIBackendBundle:Articles   
            FROM MDPIBackendBundle:Articles art
            LEFT JOIN MDPIBackendBundle:ScopusFTPUploads uploaded_art WITH art.id = uploaded_art.article_id
            WHERE uploaded_art.article_id IS NULL AND art.pubdate_published >= '".$startDate."' AND art.pubdate_published < '".$endDate."');
```